On 24.04 how can I Install GCC 14.1
I want to install G++ 14.1 on Ubuntu 24.04. I have 14.0 installed, but 14.1 fixes some bugs.
I don't want to build from source. I did a cross compiler build a few years ago and it kept crashing my machine and I don't have a wimpy machine.
